# State machine diagram versus Protocol state machine diagram

Tags: uml, state-machine

There is two types of state machine diagram:

1. State machine diagram
2. Protocol state machine

but I can't get the precise differences between them

Answer (score 6):

**Protocol state machine IS state machine**, a special case of state machine, applied to protocol specification.

- **UML state machine** defines the concepts, syntactcal rules and base semantics of state diagrams
- In case of **Protocol state machine** is this base semantics refined and put in this specific technical context.

In summary, Protocol state machine is a concrete application of a plain UML state machines to protocol specification/modelling.

You might want to read this article to learn more about the protocol state machine and how it employs UML state machine:

http://www.uml-diagrams.org/protocol-state-machine-diagrams.html

Answer (score 6):

I will try to explain the difference in very simple way:
You are right, UML defines two types of State Machine:

1. Behavioral
2. Protocolar

Behavioral state machine defines behavior with focus on how are states of system changing as a reaction to an event occurrences. It is very important to understand. Events which occurrences are accepted are defined as triggers on transitions. This type of state machine is very well known.

Protocol state machine does not primary define behavior. Its base role is to define, when and on which conditions can individual behavioral features (operations, receptions) of owning instance be invoked.

Typical examples of protocol state machine from life could be computer start process:

Lets imagine computer working states: Loading Bios, Loading OS, Prepared.
You cannot execute loading OS before Bios is Loaded, You cannot Execute your application before OS is loaded. Protocol state machine will have 3 states and two transitions. Transitions will have defined operations of computer loadBios() before loading bios state, loadOS() between states loading Bios and Loading OS.

Protocol is a set of rules to execute operations and other behavioral features of instance.

Answer (score 1):

In UML, a **protocol state machine** is the *«specification»* of set an *legal* sequences of events without specifying the behavior of an implementation (other than state changes) while a **behavioral state machine** is a *«realization»* the of a state machine may take actions (*behaviors*).

From this standpoint, a protocol state machine is like an interface (it is purely abstract) while a behavioral state machine is like a class.   A behavioral state machine can implement a protocol state machine.

You can find further details, including a non-trivial example oriented around database acces, in the article [Building Protocol State Machines in UML 2](http://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/building-protocol-state-machines-in-uml-2/), by Michael Jesse Chonoles and James A. Schardt.